# Scrollviewer position and wrapanel on 2 lines.

Tags: wpf, xaml

How do I change the ScrollViewer so that it is positioned at the bottom.

As you can see in the image, the products are placed on a single line and I want them to be on 2 lines.

How can I do this?

http://i62.tinypic.com/al5ico.jpg

```
<Grid x:Name="kinectRegionGrid" Margin="10,20,10,20" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="170" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

   <k:KinectScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Name="scrollViewer" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden " ScrollChanged="scrollViewer_ScrollChanged">
        <WrapPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="wrapPanel" Orientation="Horizontal " k:KinectTileButton.Click="KinectTileButtonClick">
            <!-- items for design layout.  They will be replaced at runtime. -->

            <Image Height="150" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" Width="200" />
        </WrapPanel>
        </k:KinectScrollViewer>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0, 10, 0, 10">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <local:KinectHoverButton Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource KinectHoverButtonScrollLeftStyle}" Click="PageLeftButtonClick" Visibility="Hidden" x:Name="lbvi" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=ControlsBasicsWindow, Path=PageLeftEnabled}"/>
        <local:KinectHoverButton Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource KinectHoverButtonScrollRightStyle}" Click="PageRightButtonClick" Visibility="Hidden" x:Name="rbvi" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=ControlsBasicsWindow, Path=PageRightEnabled}"/>
```

Comment: `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` is enabled so `WrapPanel` will be given as much horizontal space as it requires hence will never wrap its elements

Comment: i've disabled this property and the elements are still in line.. I want them 3 on one line and 3 on another line

Comment: Did you set it to `Hidden` or `Disabled`. `Hidden` still makes scrolling possible just hides scrollbar.

Comment: at first i've put "hidden", now i've put "disabled" and it works, just that there are 5 elements on the first line and the sixth is on the second line. i want 3 and 3

Comment: then instead of `WrapPanel` try `<UniformGrid ... Columns="3"`.

Comment: it's a good idea, i managed to do it. can you tell me please how to decrease the space between elements? there's a bit too much blank space between images